# UILocalNotification wants permission to show, but it is already granted

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am allowing `remote and local notifications` in my app, it works perfectly fine for `remote notifications` but when trying to use `local notifications` it then does not show the notification, but it is running the code.

Remote notifications work when I am out of the app, but local notifications don't want to show when I am in the app?

Here is the code:

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert
let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

and the receiving of the notification:

```
if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active) {
        var ln: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        ln.userInfo = userInfo
        ln.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        ln.alertBody = notification["alert"] as NSString
        ln.fireDate = NSDate()
        application.scheduleLocalNotification(ln)
        println("local")
    } else {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    }
```

When in the app, it is printing out `local`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't quite get what a local notification is. The whole point of a local notification is that it is a way for the system to notify the user on your behalf when your app isn't frontmost. If your app *is* frontmost, there is nothing more for the system to do. Local notifications, therefore, do not fire any alert to the user when the app is frontmost. Instead, if your app is frontmost when a local notification fires, your app is notified and *you* can alert the user if you like.

Comment: Then how can you add a banner yourself?

Comment: What do you mean by "add a banner"? What are you trying / hoping to do?

Comment: Do you know about UIAlertController (old UIAlertView)? Is that what you're looking for? That is the sort of thing I mean when I say "you can alert the user".

Comment: No, like using a remote notification, it pops up with a banner at the top of the screen, I need to show that in the app as well

Comment: But what do you "need" that? Look, nothing about the banner is guaranteed, so don't rely on it. The user can turn off banners for your app, in Settings! Do not get wedded to the banner idea. It is not reliable interface and you can't control whether it will appear or not.

Comment: OK, so, if your app is not frontmost and if the user has elected to permit your app to show a banner, a banner will appear when the notification fires. But if you app _is_ frontmost - dude, you own the entire screen. You control the horizontal, you control the vertical. If you want to make something that looks like a banner appear when the notification fires, make it. The screen is yours. Go for it.